# Nvidia GT 610 is not recognized

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a dedicated graphics card in my pc (Nvidia GT 610), running windows 10 pro.
But it's not detected in Cycles render settings. Pls lemme know how can i render in GPU. Kindly refer to the attached screenshots.

[image: Preferences>System>Cycles Render Devices].

[image: NVidia Control Panel System Information]

Comment: I (and all the others ending up on this post) feel your pain,  software-backed driver layering is a thing of the past now, and was originally conceived to stop these kinds of problems from happening -- but it didn't help sell video cards. Cue the entitled vce to come in and shake their fist saying for us to upgrade our potatoes secretly staffed by NVIDIA or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graphics card has a CUDA compute capability of 2.1, however [GPU rendering in Blender 2.8 requires a compute capability of 3.0](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware). That is why your graphics card isn't listed.